# Unable to tar+gzip git directory with local operation

Tags: python, deployment, fabric

I'm trying to create automatic deployment script for my Django based project. Basically everything works fine, till the step where I'm trying to compress my project directory. Fabric seem to execute command, it does not return any errors.

Here is the line which is causing problems:

```
local('git archive -v --format=tar HEAD | gzip > test.tar.gz')
```

I'm using Windows with Cygwin to have access to Unix commands. I tried to execute the same command in the project's root directory (from Cygwin) and `test.tar.gz` was created successfully (120 MB). I'm also executing the Fabric script from project's root directory (using Cygwin) and after execution I see `test.tar.gz` gets created but it is simply empty (20 bytes).

EDIT: tried to run the same script on my colleagues Linux machine and it worked perfectly :S

EDIT 2: I tried to execute instead of local, subprocess.Popen command in fabfile, which performed correctly what I needed.. Now there is a question, why the same command in local method(found in operations.py source) does not perform the task?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is Python, Django, Fabric, etc. installed in Cygwin or just on the same machine?

Comment: Yes, its on the same machine. It just appears that somehow fabric local command doesn't "wait" for completion of git archive, because generally it takes few seconds to complete when I run command directly.. But when commant is run with fabric it returns immediately :-S

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is [Cygwin's environment variables](http://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using-cygwinenv.html) are not available to the system shell that is being called by [`local()`](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.8/api/core/operations.html?highlight=local#fabric.operations.local),

> local is simply a convenience wrapper around the use of the builtin
>   Python subprocess module with shell=True activated. If you need to do
>   anything special, consider using the subprocess module directly.

which is why they also provided [`run()`](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.8/api/core/operations.html?highlight=local#fabric.operations.run). This gives you the ability to run shell commands on a remote host. You *could* (in theory) create a bash file that invokes Cygwin then calls your `git archive` command. I would **not** recommend this however and [here](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.8/faq.html#my-cd-workon-export-etc-calls-don-t-seem-to-work) is why.

If you simply need the ability to invoke git commands I would highly recommend using [msysGit](https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit). After installing, set your `PATH` environment variable to point to where msysgit's bin is so you can invoke git commands from the CMD.